# Project Structure in .NET -- inject various custom services into application

Tags: c#, .net-core, architecture

I am developing a console app in C# 6.  The purpose of the console app is basically to drive four similar "worker" services.  Two of the services will be closed-source, but I intend to open-source the other two services and the code itself.  My users will have two options, based on their comfort with a closed source product:

*"Closed Source" version:*

Console Application Drives:

- Open Source Worker 1
- Open Source Worker 2
- Closed Source Worker 1
- Closed Source Worker 2

*"Open Source" version (will be made available on github):*

Console Application Drives:

- Open Source Worker 1
- Open Source Worker 2

I want to design this to have as much code/assembly reuse as possible, to reduce repetition when building and deploying both versions of the application.  I'm considering putting the open source workers in one project/assembly, the closed source in a second assembly, and then having the console application be a small project that somehow locates all relevant dlls and dynamically loads the types from those dlls through reflection to figure out which types of workers to instantiate.  Or maybe code the workers to instantiate more explicitly in an appsettings.json file so there's less reflection scanning.

Anyway, other than the specifics of the open/closed source stuff, I'd imagine I'm not the first to get into a requirement like this.  Are there any conventions or recommendations on the best way to design this?

Comment: This depends on how you expect the open source user to consume your service. Maybe you should think about the open source component as a nuget package, with a sample project showing how to use it...

Comment: Possibly.  The service is not really intended for developers-- the only reason for the open-source approach is trust, as the subject matter is sensitive, and I am hoping allowing users to review the code and verify it, and also providing MSBuild steps to compile at home would give concerned users a more trustworthy option.